# Created LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer combined with TermQuery not returning results

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am using a PerFieldAnalyzer to set ExactTitle to use a new LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer:

```
private Analyzer GetDefaultAnalyzer()
    {
        var perFieldAnalyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));
        perFieldAnalyzer.AddAnalyzer(ReportFields.ExactTitle, new LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer());
...
```

I'm building the index, adding in the field:

```
var exactTitleField = new Field(ReportFields.ExactTitle, report.PortalReportTitle, Field.Store.NO,
                                            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
            exactTitleField.Boost = 10.0f;
            reportDoc.Add(exactTitleField);
```

When I search on it using a 2 word example "test abc", it is failing to find it when I do a TermQuery search for it:

```
var term = new Term(exactField, "test abc");
var exactQuery = new TermQuery(term);
query.Add(exactQuery,Occur.SHOULD);
var hits = searcher.Search(query, null, HitsLimit, Sort.RELEVANCE);
```

If I do a search for "Test Abc", it works.  What can I do to make this case insensitive keyword/term search work?

Here's the analyzer:

```
public class LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer : Analyzer
{

    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        TokenStream tokenStream = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
        tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenStream);
        return tokenStream;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED` when you create your field, the analyzer will not be run and the text will not be transformed to Lower case

Switch it for `Field.Index.ANALYZED`

**EDIT**

Perhaps there is an issue with your indexing code, and also dont forget that if you lower case at indexing time, you will also the to lower case the input at search time to get a match.

Since you build your query manually, you will need to handle it yourself. Ideally you want to run the same `Analyzer` on the string before constructing your `Term` at search time.

I've put up a quick little sample that does what you seem to be trying to do, maybe it'll help you figure out what is wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Store;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();
            var perFieldAnalyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
            perFieldAnalyzer.AddAnalyzer("ExactTitle", new LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer());

            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, perFieldAnalyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

            Document reportDoc = new Document();
            Field exactTitleField = new Field("ExactTitle", 
                                                "Test Abc", 
                                                Field.Store.NO,
                                                Field.Index.ANALYZED);

            reportDoc.Add(exactTitleField);
            indexWriter.AddDocument(reportDoc);
            indexWriter.Commit();

            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexWriter.GetReader());

            var term = new Term("ExactTitle", "test abc"); //note: for this to work this way you need to always lower case the search too
            var exactQuery = new TermQuery(term);

            var hits = searcher.Search(exactQuery, null, 25, Sort.RELEVANCE);
            Console.WriteLine(hits.TotalHits); // prints "1"
            Console.ReadLine();

            indexWriter.Close();

        }

        public class LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer : Analyzer
        {

            public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
            {
                TokenStream tokenStream = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
                tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenStream);
                return tokenStream;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  When I switch it to ANALYZED, though, NEITHER "test abc" or "Test Abc" is found.  Do you see anything else I missed?

Comment: Thank you very much for posting the code.  It turned out that I had not been setting the analyzer properly when indexing (multiple methods, changed 1 and hit the other).  That being said, you helped me beyond the next problem, in mentioning that I need to lowercase the input being searched.  Thanks again!